# In HTML5 will the values of date and datetime fields be returned in a canonical format regardless of locale?

Tags: html

If I were to access the `value` of a `date` or `datetime` element, will the value be returned in a canonical form (eg: `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) regardless of locale? I would imagine something like this would be necessary instead having the developer deal with the different locale-specific date-formats. Is there any part of the HTML5 specification that mentions this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I should have searched a little more. According to [§4.10.1.5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#input-author-notes)

> In some locales, however, times are often expressed differently when presented to users. For example, in the United States, it is still common to use the 12-hour clock with an am/pm indicator, as in "2pm". In France, it is common to separate the hours from the minutes using an "h" character, as in "14h00".
>
> Similar issues exist with dates, with the added complication that even the order of the components is not always consistent — for example, in Cyprus the first of February 2003 would typically be written "1/2/03", while that same date in Japan would typically be written as "2003年02月01日" — and even with numbers, where locales differ, for example, in what punctuation is used as the decimal separator and the thousands separator.
>
> It therefore is important to distinguish the time, date, and number formats used in HTML and in form submissions, which are always the formats defined in this specification (and based on the well-established ISO 8601 standard for computer-readable date and time formats), from the time, date, and number formats presented to the user by the browser and accepted as input from the user by the browser.
>
> The format used "on the wire", i.e. in HTML markup and in form submissions, is intended to be computer-readable and consistent irrespective of the user's locale. Dates, for instance, are always written in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", as in "2003-02-01". Users are not expected to ever see this format.
>
> The time, date, or number given by the page in the wire format is then translated to the user's preferred presentation (based on user preferences or on the locale of the page itself), before being displayed to the user. **Similarly, after the user inputs a time, date, or number using their preferred format, the user agent converts it back to the wire format before putting it in the DOM or submitting it**.
>
> **This allows scripts in pages and on servers to process times, dates, and numbers in a consistent manner without needing to support dozens of different formats, while still supporting the users' needs**.